# Exporting two Access tables to the same excel tab

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I was wondering if it was possible to export two access tables to the same excel tab not just sheet. I am trying to join both tables on the same page. Does anybody know how to do this or any other solutions that could help?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not run a union query of both tables and export to worksheet? Otherwise, open tables in VBA recordsets and output to Excel range using [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an relation between the tables then you can create a query in access and then export the query

Comment: They are two separate tables that do not have a relationship... I do not want them to be joined together

Comment: Then my only solution is java ; )  odbc driver and poi

Answer (score 0):

Since tables are not related, use in Access VBA `CopyFromRecordset` to output tables to specific ranges of Excel worksheet. You will need to reference only the top left most corner cell (so be sure to account for columns and rows of tables to not overlap data):

```
Public Sub acToxlRecordsets()

    Dim xlApp As Object, xlwkb As Object
    Dim db As Database
    Dim frst As Recordset, srst As Recordset    
    Dim strPath As String

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    strPath = "C:\Path\To\Excel\Workbook.xlsx"

    Set xlwkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

    ' OPEN FIRST RECORDSET
    Set frst = db.OpenRecordset("FirstTable", dbOpenDynaset)
    frst.MoveFirst

    ' OUTPUT RECORDSET (SELECT TOP LEFT CORNER --CHANGE SHEET AS NEEDED)         
    xlwkb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CopyfromRecordset frst
    frst.Close

    ' OPEN SECOND RECORDSET
    Set frst = db.OpenRecordset("SecondTable", dbOpenDynaset)
    srst.MoveFirst

    ' OUTPUT RECORDSET (SELECT TOP LEFT CORNER --CHANGE SHEET AS NEEDED)        
    xlwkb.Worksheets(1).Range("J1").CopyfromRecordset srst
    srst.Close

    ' SAVE AND CLOSE EXCEL WORKBOOK
    xlwkb.Close True
    xlApp.Quit

    Set xlwkb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set frst = Nothing
    Set srst = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing   

End Sub
```